# How to auto-scroll a webpage as elements are added above?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I am often on a webpage, and am about to click a link when the page simultaneously adds an element that it had been waiting to asynchronously receive from the server.  The element that I was about to click suddenly lurches downward, and I click on an entirely different element that sends me who-knows-where.  This happens with an incredible frequency, and the general behavior causes me frustration in other browser-based apps (such as with jupyter notebook).

I realize that since the page may add items anywhere, including in the middle of what I'm currently viewing, it is impossible to ensure a perfectly consistent view given the reality of dynamic websites.  However, even when items are added *outside of what I'm currently viewing*, what I'm currently viewing changes by being forced off-screen.  I would like to prevent this behavior by auto-scrolling the page to maintain a persistent viewport location for, e.g., the stuff at the bottom of my current viewport.

In any of the "big" browsers, (firefox, chrome, etc), is it possible to auto-scroll to maintain something like a consistent viewport during dynamic page updates?

Comment: Welcome. This site is about using web applications and the questions should be specific. Questions about web browsers could be done on other sites like [su] but before posting or asking to migrate a question to that sites please checkout their how to ask guidelines. If you wan to keep your question on this site please choose an specific web app and specific web browser and [edit] the question accordingly.